# List of file types php

Tags: php, file-type

I'm looking for a list/description detailing the file type `php` assigns based on an uploaded file.

I have the following script. It takes the uploaded file, and the file type. Compares it to the array to check if the type is allowed and then proceeds with the script.

```
$file  = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];

//check file is correct type
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
// array of allowed file extensions
$fileTypeArray = ["application/pdf", "application/doc", "application/docx", "application/rtf", "application/txt", "application/odf", "application/msword"];


// now check that the file type matches that of the array. 
if (!in_array($fileType, $fileTypeArray)){
```

I would like to allow the upload of any `doc`, `pdf`, `txt`, etc.  Its purpose is to handle uploaded cv's. Please tell me if you can think of a better solution. Cheers!

Comment: [knock yourself out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) :) I think you want to manually define your `$fileTypeArray`, unless you want all existing types to be allowed?

Comment: thanks Felix, thats great! Would you say thats a comprehensive list?

Comment: at least comprehensible :)

Comment: As you might have guessed by now: The list of file types is unending. Anybody can make up a new file type, and use it. It would be stupid if someone said: "These are all the types and that's the end of that.". You can try to have a long list, but it will never be complete. There's also, for the same reason, no list present in PHP anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These media types are in fact MIME types and PHP manages them (following excerpt taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types))

> A media type (also known as a Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions or MIME type) is a standard that indicates the nature and format of a document, file, or assortment of bytes. It is defined and standardized in IETF's [RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838).

> The [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](https://www.iana.org/) is responsible for all official MIME types, and you can find the most up-to-date and complete list at their [Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) page.

There are a few of them, and the list is subject to expansion.

---

For your comparison, I think you want to manually define the acceptable types, as using a generic types list would result in all types being acceptable (which does not seem to be your goal)

I'd also add the link towards [the input man page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) and suggest you read about the `accept` attribute, which can filter your files **right on client side**

> If the value of the type attribute is file, this attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content type specifiers:

Don't let the text fool you; users won't be able to select the file if it's not in `accept`ed file types, but do note that the server needs to validate that as well as it is possible to submit a form to a server directly and bypass any client validation.

Comment: Many thanks for elaborating Felix, have also implemented on client side :)